# Python Scoping Issue, variables reset every iteration of a loop

Tags: python, scoping

The following python block should add two binary number strings. The variables `res_str` and `carry` are being reset to their initial values every iteration of the loop.

```
class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a, b):
        """
        :type a: str
        :type b: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        if len(a) < len(b):
            a.zfill(len(b))
        elif len(a) > len(b):
            b.zfill(len(a))

        res_str = ''
        carry = '0'
        for asub, bsub in reversed(list(zip(a, b))):
            print(res_str, carry)
            if asub == '1' and bsub == '1':
                res_str = '0' + res_str
                carry = '1' + carry
            elif asub == '1' or bsub == '1':
                res_str = '1' + res_str
                carry = '0' + carry
            else:
                res_str = '0' + res_str
                carry = '0' + carry
            print(res_str, carry)

        if '1' in carry:
            return self.addBinary(res_str, carry)
        else:
            return res_str

s = Solution()
s.addBinary('1', '11')
#   0
# 0 10
#   0
# 1 00
# 1
```

At the beginning of each iteration of the loop, their values are `''` and `0` respectively. Their values are altered during the loop block but they are reset.

I've tried changing these to class variables (`self.res_str` and `self.carry`) with the same results.

What's causing these variables to be reset?

edit: forgot to use the output of `zfill`

Comment: That's not resetting. That's the recursive call having its own `res_str` and `carry`.

Comment: You forgot to do anything with the `zfill` output.